# SelectedItem in MultiColumnComboBox is Null

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, null

I'm writing on a WPF. In it I use a MultiColumnComboBox to select some values. Which looks like this.

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="OutputMatrNr" IsTextSearchEnabled="False" IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}" IsDropDownOpen="False" StaysOpenOnEdit="True" KeyUp="OutputMatrNr_KeyUp" DropDownClosed="ComboBoxStudentOnDropDown" KeyDown="ComboBoxStudentOnKeyPress" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=students, Mode=TwoWay}" BorderThickness="2px" BorderBrush="black" Canvas.Left="2px" Canvas.Top="18px" Width="100px">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding MatrNr}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid x:Name="gd" TextElement.Foreground="Black">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding MatrNr}"/>
                            <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding NachName}"/>
                            <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding VorName}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

Here is the Code behind.

```
protected void ComboBoxStudentOnDropDown(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (((Student)OutputMatrNr.SelectedItem).Equals(null)){ // here sometimes the System.NullReferenceException occures
            FillStudentFromComboBox(((Student)OutputMatrNr.SelectedItem).MatrNr.ToString()); // I never(!) get here
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("else");
        }
    }

    protected void ComboBoxStudentOnKeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            FillStudentFromComboBox(OutputMatrNr.Text); //this works every time
        }
    }
```

If a MatrNr is written in the ComboBox I filter for what is written in it. If you write the full Nr and press enter everything works just fine. 
But if you click on a Student I always get Null in return (ending in the else case). Also I get a System.NullReferenceException which occures every once in a while and I cant reproduce the error exactly.
I am missing something but I cant figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `OutputMatrNr.SelectedItem` may be null. That is why you are getting NullReferenceException. So the IF condition should be changed like this.

```
if (OutputMatrNr.SelectedItem != null && OutputMatrNr.SelectedItem is Student)
{                
    FillStudentFromComboBox(((Student)OutputMatrNr.SelectedItem).MatrNr.ToString());
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("else");
}
```

Also as per your code behind the `SelectedItem` is of type `Student`. But in the xaml you are binding the `SelectedItem` to `students`. If it is Students, then you need to change the xaml accordingly.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="OutputMatrNr" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Student, Mode=TwoWay}"....>
```

Comment: Ah yes. I see.
Thank you for pointing that out. Now it works fine.